# Experiencing problems filtering view programmatically

Tags: 8, views

I'm using a views block in my website, the content of this view is filtered programmatically. I now get messages from users who see the wrong information. The filter is based on the currently logged in user. Since I need this information in the regular filter and not in the contextual filter I created a simple module to change the filter value.

My filter is like this:

```
(
Content type = contenttype_a
AND
uid(nodes author) = */this value is programmatically added*/
)

OR

(
Content type = contenttype_b
AND
user_target_id(reference) =  */this value is programmatically added*/
)
```

Than I use this in my module:

```
 */
function entity_access_views_pre_view(ViewExecutable $view, $display_id, array &$args){
  $currentUser = \Drupal::currentUser();
  $cuid = $currentUser->id();

    /* @ Filter View: Media  */
    if ($view->id() == 'my_view_id') {
      if ($display_id == 'block_1' || $display_id == 'page_1' || $display_id == 'page_2') {
        $filters = $view->display_handler->getOption('filters');
        $filters['uid']['value']['value'] = $cuid;
        $filters['user_target_id']['value']['value'] = $cuid;
        $view->display_handler->overrideOption('filters', $filters);
      }
    }
}
```

Since I can't seem to find the problem I'm having doubts about if above is working as I want it to. So I wanted to check if you see anything strange or false. Can this filter value be cached in some way? Or maybe there is a better way to do this.

I can't use the contextual filter, which I would prefer, because the view is showing two content types where on each content type the filter should be different.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First you can try to add a cache context to the render element of the View before it is rendered:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_render().
 *
 */
function mymodule_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view) {
  if ($view->id() == 'my_view_id') {
    if ($view->current_display == 'block_1') {
      $view->element['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'user';
      // or add a cache max-age 0 for a high user count
      $view->element['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

This doesn't help however if Views is caching the query internally. Then you can try to disable caching by configuring the *None* or *Time-based*  cache plugin within the View. You can't configure a cache context here, though, only a cache max-age of 0. This is not necessarily a bad idea if you have a high user count and don't want to cache the same amount of variants. Drupal has a great caching system for delivering non-cacheable blocks to authenticated users (Dynamic Page Cache + BigPipe).

Comment: Thanks, disabling the cache in the view itself is my first try to solve this. I'm now waiting to see if this solves the problem.